# Mailman / Postfix Configuration Assistance

Tags: rhel, postfix, mailman

I am writing for some help regarding Postfix configuration.

I cannot seem to get Postfix configured properly to transfer mail to the mailing list installed on the same server. I followed many steps over the last few days, and the last one I followed is at http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html under the section Mailing Lists.

Can someone please look at this and let me know what I am missing?

Basically, Postfix has been configured for base email to be sent to `xxx@mail-test.company.org` and I would like the mail list to use `xxx@listtest.company.org`.

```
**DYN-DNS** 
listtest.company.org        A   216.111.222.85   
listtest.company.org        MX  216.111.222.85   
listtest.company.org        TXT     "v=spf1 a ptr mx ip4:216.111.222.85 mx:mail-test.company.org -all"

mail-test.company.org       A   216.111.222.85   
mail-test.company.org       MX  216.111.222.85   
mail-test.company.org       TXT     "v=spf1 a ptr mx ip4:216.111.222.85 mx:mail-test.company.org -all"

**main.cf**
myhostname = mail-test.company.org
mydomain = company.org
myorigin = $hostname
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/etc/mailman/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/etc/mailman/aliases 
recipient_delimiter = +
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual 
mydestination = $myhostname, listtest.$mydomain

/etc/postfix/virtual:
    listname-request@listtest.company.org   listname-request
    listname@listtest.company.org               listname
    owner-listname@listtest.company.org     owner-listname

/etc/aliases:
    listname: "/usr/lib/mailman/mail/mailman post mailman"
    owner-listname: ...
    listname-request: ...

**mm_cfg.py**
DEFAULT_URL_HOST   = 'listtest.company.org'
DEFAULT_EMAIL_HOST = 'listtest.company.org'
add_virtualhost(DEFAULT_URL_HOST, DEFAULT_EMAIL_HOST)
MTA = 'Postfix'
```

The first part of the log shows the rejection of listtest.company.org -- whereas the second part shows successful transfer to mail-test.company.org

**/var/log/maillog**

```
Aug 17 15:46:50 listserv postfix/smtpd[19870]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from
Mail1.company.org[66.173.196.101]: 554 5.7.1 <XXXX@listtest.company.org>: 
Relay access denied; from=<user@company1.ORG> to=<list@listtest.company.org> 
proto=SMTP helo=<MAIL1.company.ORG>
Aug 17 15:46:50 listserv postfix/cleanup[19877]: D3F93209F1: message-
id=<050C37C3BC21CC4483AC395BAFEC94E506116BF5@mail1.informs.org>
Aug 17 15:46:50 listserv postfix/smtpd[19870]: disconnect from 
Mail1.company.org[66.173.196.101]

Aug 17 15:46:50 listserv postfix/qmgr[19197]: D3F93209F1: 
from=<user2@company.ORG>, size=6670, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 17 15:46:50 listserv postfix/cleanup[19877]: F37B120A3B: message-
id=<050C37C3BC21CC4483AC395BAFEC94E506116BF5@mail1.informs.org>
Aug 17 15:46:51 listserv postfix/qmgr[19197]: F37B120A3B: 
from=<user2@company.ORG>, size=6819, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 17 15:46:51 listserv postfix/local[19878]: D3F93209F1:
to=<company_it@mail-test.company.org>, relay=local, delay=0.18,
delays=0.17/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as F37B120A3B)
Aug 17 15:46:51 app02-listserv postfix/qmgr[19197]: D3F93209F1: removed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It was a mm_cfg.py config problem with the virtual alias table. Once corrected, and POSTALIAS run, it is now forwarding email correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I added mailman to my working postfix setup by following the instructions here: http://sharealike.org/index.php/2011/02/04/adding-mailman-to-postfix-with-virtual-domains/ I think this will work well for you because I also use a different subdomain for lists.example.com from the primary domain.